# Using Jest with NodeJS, Function in imported module not being mocked without using 'this' in main

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

In the setup below, if I run the test as is, `myFunc` is not mocked when I debug into `handler`.

However, if instead I add `this.` in front of the `myFunc` call in `handler`, then the function is mocked and everything works as expected.

Can someone please explain why this is? I'm new to mocking and can't see it.

I know what `this` does, but why won't jest mock without it since I told it to mock that function in the module?

`index.js`

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

  exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
  
    let s;
    switch (event.func) {
      case "myFunc":
        console.log('Executing myFunc');
        //making the call: s = await this.myFunc.apply(null, [event.params]) will make the mock work.
        s = await myFunc.apply(null, [event.params]) 
        console.log(s);
        return s;
      /*cases...*/
      default:
      // default behaviour
    }

    async myFunc({p1, p2}){
        /* do something */
        return x
    }
    exports.myFunc = myFunc
  }
```

`index.spec.js`

```
jest.mock('./index.js', () => {

    const allAutoMocked = jest.createMockFromModule('./index.js')
 
    const actual = jest.requireActual('./index.js')
  
    return {
      __esModules: true,
  
      ...allAutoMocked,
  
      myFunc : jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ mockedValue: 'test' })),
  
      handler: actual.handler
    }
  })

let index = require("./index.js")

describe('Test myFunc', () => {
        
    test('If myFunc function was called', async () => {
        var event = { func: 'myFunc', params: { p1: xx, p2: false } };
        const context = {};
        const logMock = jest.fn((...args) => console.log(...args));

        const data = await handler(event, context);
    })
})
```

Comment: Since you are using `function` keyword, the `this` inside the handler is a reference to `exports` object

Comment: Without the 'function' keyword it's worse, even adding 'this' will not make it work.

Comment: I’m not saying it’s a cause of the issue. I’m just explaining how it works.